# How to make this pattern in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is the pattern I need:

```
min(E2:E9)

min(E26:E33)

min(E50:E57)

....
```

It's pretty clear, the first number start with 2 and increases by 24, while the second number is the first number +7.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Which cell will you enter the first formula?

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
=MIN(INDEX(E:E,24*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+2):INDEX(E:E,24*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+9))
```

and copy downwards.

This produces the equivalent to:

```
=MIN(E2:E9)
=MIN(E26:E33)
=MIN(E50:E57)
=MIN(E74:E81)
=MIN(E98:E105)
=MIN(E122:E129)
=MIN(E146:E153)
=MIN(E170:E177)
=MIN(E194:E201)
=MIN(E218:E225)
=MIN(E242:E249)
=MIN(E266:E273)
=MIN(E290:E297)
```